# Inserting duplicated MySQL test data the easy way?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Rather than creating row after row of test data one at a time, is there a query I could run in MySQL to do the following:

Table name: my_table
Rows consist of: ID (auto-incremental), fname, lname, email, phone

The test data should be duplicated into 100 rows, where the data would be:

```
1   John   Doe   jdoe@jdoe.com   0000000  
2   John   Doe   jdoe@jdoe.com   0000000  
...  
100   John   Doe   jdoe@jdoe.com   0000000
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can write a loop do it in server languages like php, or write mysql function/prucedure with loop like : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0201__Procedure-Function/Insertdatainawhileloop.htm

Comment: @Haim: No loop needed for such a simple insert. And if he wants to add a million rows, a loop will be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL should do the trick - just modify the INSERT

```
DELIMITER //


CREATE PROCEDURE addItems(number INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET number = number - 1;
    INSERT ....
    IF number <> 0 THEN ITERATE label1; END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
CALL addItems(100);
```

Comment: Thanks! What would I modify the INSERT to?

Answer (score 6):

One way to do that is to use an existing table that has as many rows as you want to insert into your new table. suppose the existing table is `old_table` and it has 100 (or more) rows of any data, here is what you would do:

```
insert into my_table (fname,lname,email,phone)
    select 'John', 'Doe', 'jdoe@jdoe.com', '0000000' 
    from old_table
    limit 100
```

If the primary key in my_table is auto increment then this should work

Comment: Add a `LIMIT 100` in your select, so it will work with any bigger `old_table` too :)

Comment: Only issue is that I don't have an already existing table :) Just wanted the easiest way through an SQL query.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an unnamed block and use a loop inside to execute a query 100 times.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;

  WHILE v1 < 100 DO
    INSERT INTO my_table (ID, fname, lname, email, phone) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'John', 'Doe', 'jdoe@jdoe.com', '000000');
    SET v1 = v1 + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a simple piece of code that does this for you. Since your ID is auto incremental, it would be something like:

```
<?php
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, email, phone) VALUES ";

 for($i=0;$<=100;$i++)
    $sql .= "('John', 'Doe', 'jdoe@jdoe.com', '0000000'),";   

 mysql_query(substr($sql, 0, -1));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried, yet it didn't insert? :(

Comment: I assume you did a mysql_connect and a mysql_select_db first?

Comment: Yup!  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
 mysql_select_db("dbname");

Comment: Does it work if you output the $sql variable and paste it directly into some sql administrator application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try http://www.generatedata.com/#generator Under Options you can enter the duplicate values.